# How are keys stored and accessed in python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement DFS and BFS in python. I have this code for Depth First Search, which works and I almost understand it.

What I don't understand is how are the keys being accessed. The program could have chosen any key in G.keys(),but it always ends up choosing the next adjacent key in the graph. Since I have stored the Graph as a dictionary,how does the program know which key to choose next. Does it happen randomly or is there a specific reason? Please help me understand the internal working.

```js
Graph={'A':['B','G','D'],
 'B':['E','F'],
 'C':['F','H'],
 'D':['A','F'],
 'E':['B','G'],
 'F':['B','D','C'],
 'G':['E','A'],
 'H':['C']}


def traverse(G,node,visited):
 visited[node]=True
 print 'node:'+node+
 for other_nodes in G[node]:
  if other_nodes not in visited:
   traverse(G,other_nodes,visited)

def start_traversal(G):
 visited={}
 for node in G.keys():
  if node not in visited:
   traverse(G,node,visited)

start_traversal(Graph)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start_traversal` is not where the adjacent key is chosen. That's the part in `traverse`, specifically `for other_nodes in G[node]:`. Since `G[node]` contains only adjacent nodes, all of them will be iterated over.

What `for node in G.keys():` does is select a random node to start from (and following nodes just in case there's a number of disconnected subgraphs in `G`).

Choosing the adjacent node does not have anything to do with hash order in this case (which you should never rely on).

Comment: Ah! yes! my mind couldn't picture the recursive nature of the program. Tried writing things out and was clear. Thanks! However,in line 'for other_nodes in G[node]:' are the values of the corresponding key selected randomly? For example,if they were chosen in increasing order of ascii value,the answer would have been ABEGFCHD,but the program returns the answer ABEGFDCH.

Comment: Yes, they are (hopefully) random. Dictionary orders are random from one run of the application to another unless you set specific PYTHONHASHSEED. Otherwise you enable someone outside to DoS your application like in this scenario: http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/12/huge-portions-of-web-vulnerable-to-hashing-denial-of-service-attack/

Answer (score 0):

The storage of a dictionary tends to be in the order of the hashes of its keys, although this is not guaranteed. You can see that in your particular example, the hashes all rise in relation to the character.

```
>>> for x in 'ABCDEFGH':
    print hash(x)

-269909568
-141909181
-13908798
114091589
242091972
370092359
498092742
626093129
```

You can use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) if you need to specify the exact order of a dictionary.

Comment: It's notable that this is not behavior to be relied upon, as depending on your implementation hash values may change per-session - i.e. hash('a') might be `3344393` one session, reset the shell and it could come back to be `-374835989`.

Comment: @Delioth that's why I said "this is not guaranteed".

Comment: Ah, I interpreted it as "in the order of hashes... although [ordering based on hashes] is not guaranteed", as opposed to "...although [ordering of those hashes] is not guaranteed." Just attempting to clarify

Comment: @Delioth what I really meant to say was, don't ever count on the order of items in a normal dictionary - the reasons are immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

first of all their is a error in the program in line: 13 col:19 it must be 
print 'node:'+node

it you want the output in the same line you can add a comma after node

second thing a dictionary stored the elements in the sorted order of ascii value of the keys

but in your program what is happening is in line 20 the node is 'A' and when you try to traverse it then in line 14 the other_nodes become one of the values in list stored as the value of key 'A' i.e. 'B'since 'B' is also a key then in another step other_nodes will be 'E'then "E" works as a key for "B" but is already is in visited so it turns to "G" and the process goes on and till the time this recursion is over all the keys are present in the visited list so your result is disorder.

Comment: thanks. I understand the program now,though,if it were stored in sorted order of ascii values,shouldn't the answer be ABEGFCHD? This program however gives an output of ABEGFDCH. That's where I got confused. While checking for the values of the F key, why was D chosen over C?

Comment: according to what  you had done this output is correct actually you might thought that at "F" it is going back to line 20 but once it falls in recurrsion it is not coming out of it at "F" it make other_nodes as "D" and "C" since the values from "D" are already presented in visited so it turn to the values of "C" since from "C" the value "F" is presented in visited so the only value left is "H" and in mean while all the keys are printed so the recursion is over and the for  loop in line 20 is off no use. And if want to check than add a "print node" statement after line 21 to check.